# How can I find out how many stored procedures I have in a database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, count

How can I find out how many stored procedures I have in a database?

(with Object Explorer and without writing a new query)

Comment: Er.... probably not on *Christmas day*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the stored procedure node in SSMS and I think it is F8.

Or view menu, object explorer details.

I don't have SSMS to check sorry

Answer (score 1):

(the Christmas guests have left) .... The number of stored procs are available *only* from the Object Explorer Details, which is available by pressing `F7` on your database in Object Explorer - dig into the stored procedures, and you should see something like:

[image]

Comment: marc_s -> i did your way / but i did not find the number of sp / where is that ?

Comment: @LostLord: see my rounded red rectangle in the screenshot ?? That's where it is. This is SSMS for SQL Server 2008 R2 - not sure if it might not be present in the 2008 version....